# KVM gets stuck at “Booting from ROM”

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, xml

I created I a ubuntu 16.04 vm with a kickstart file using the following xml

```
<domain type="kvm">
<name>""" + name + """</name>
<memory unit='GB'>1</memory>
<vcpu>1</vcpu>
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc'>hvm</type>
  <kernel>/var/lib/libvirt/media/./casper/vmlinuz.efi</kernel>
  <initrd>/var/lib/libvirt/media/./casper/initrd.lz</initrd>
  <cmdline>console=ttyS0 ks=https://pastebin.com/raw/6TznVUuN</cmdline>
</os>
<iothreads>1</iothreads>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>preserve</on_crash>
<devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/pool/""" + name + """.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/iso/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdb' bus='virtio'/>
    <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='en-us'/>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

But when I try and boot the VM it gets stuck on a screen that says

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.10.2-1ubuntu1)
Machine UUID (then id)

IPXE (url, etc..)

Booting from ROM...
```

When I check the error log of the vm it shows this only

```
2018-03-07 11:30:04.304+0000: starting up libvirt version: 3.6.0, package: 1ubuntu5 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Thu, 28 Sep 2017 08:18:10 -0400), qemu version: 2.10.1(Debian 1:2.10+dfsg-0ubuntu3), hostname: john-XPS-13-9343
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=loaderless,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-3-loaderless/master-key.aes -machine pc-i440fx-2.10,accel=kvm,usb=off,dump-guest-core=off -m 954 -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -object iothread,id=iothread1 -uuid 1630b530-3291-4168-a4c0-ec231333c6b4 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-3-loaderless/monitor.sock,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -no-acpi -boot strict=on -kernel /var/lib/libvirt/media/./casper/vmlinuz.efi -initrd /var/lib/libvirt/media/./casper/initrd.lz -append 'console=ttyS0 ks=https://pastebin.com/raw/6TznVUuN' -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/pool/loaderless.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/iso/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso,format=raw,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-virtio-disk1,readonly=on -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-disk1 -netdev tap,fd=25,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=27 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:f8:96:69,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -vnc 0.0.0.0:0 -k en-us -device cirrus-vga,id=video0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -msg timestamp=on
warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

Comment: You seem to have set up a BIOS booting VM, but expect to boot a kernel with UEFI. Something went terribly wrong here. Open up virt-manager and try re-creating the VM.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to make this with libvirt and xml.  I tried mounting the iso file to the media directory as shown here[https://askubuntu.com/a/193632/525195] and then grabbing the `vmlinuz.efi` and `initrd` from the mount spot

Comment: OK, well then please use `virt-install` to generate the XML. You're just going to save yourself a lot of trouble.